# Is There A Way To Use Late Binding For WithEvents?

Tags: vba, ms-access

On A new Windows 10 Pro PC version 1909, My Access 2007 would not recognize Word 2007, giving an error message that the MSWORD.OLB file was not Registered. (In fact, the reference to MSWORD.OLB is present and checked.)

I received a reply on this forum that I could get around this problem by using late binding. Making this change, the error disappeared.

Still no go, however, using automation and WithEvents.

In the Class Module:

`Public WithEvents objWord As Object (or Application)` generates a compile error "Missing Identification"

`Public WithEvents objWord As Word.Application` doesn't raise a compile error, but at runtime, I again get the "Library Not Registered" error.

Is there something I'm not doing?

I have had one reply questioning whether referencing is the same as registering a library. The .OLB file type can't be registered (the way a .dll file can be). The error code is a non sequitur. MSWORD.OLB doesn't need to be registered. It just "is."

My problem probably has something to do with the exact coding inside my version of Windows 10 Pro. I have another machine running the same version number, but it's Windows 10 Home. Works fine even with early binding.

My last-gasp attempt to solve my problem will be to re-install a Home version.

Comment: Not sure, but is registering the library the same as adding a reference to it? Have a feeling it's not.